# "Unexpected token ERROR found" error shown at netbeans working on a jsf project for percent (%) character

Tags: jsf, netbeans, xml-encoding

I am facing a strange issue with netbeans and jsf, it is not fatal but quite annoying.

For some reason I am getting the error "Unexpected character % found Unexpected token ERROR found" from netbeans for the following code block.

It is complaining about the percent sign, do you have any idea how to resolve this? I tried to escape it with xml encoding of percent with "%" but then it started complaining about & character..

```
<div class="bar" style="width: #{cc.value.relevance}%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho, 
You should add a cast like:

```
object.toString().append("%");
```

before it gets call by the front-end.

Comment: Thats not a convenient use, I have several fields like that and they are part of an object modal, so I am looking for a front-end solution, but thanks anyway for the feedback.

Comment: What type of variable is this bean call returning?

Comment: It's a double value. But its a field of a Morphia object modal.

Comment: I still would recommend to parse it to String. It is better if you follow up with a pattern so if you have many pages and forget to put the "%" in one of them nothing will complain about it. So passing a string build with the "%" sign will make it more secure and you won't have to worry about it. Another thing is that you need a String builder in order to use the "append()" method, or you could do `object.toString() + "%";` .

Comment: I use this pattern for another case and it is a nice workaround thanks for the feedback. But it seems like a bug of the IDE (netbeans), these kind of examples should not be marked as error.

Comment: What does it complains about?

Comment: It does complain about the following code and thats annoying, otherwise your method works ok =)<div class="bar" style="width: #{cc.value.relevance}%;"></div>